# contents of standard output is incorrect

Tags: c

Given  a int  variable  named  yesCount and another int  variable  named  noCount and a char  variable  named  response, write the necessary code to read a value  into into response and then carry out the following:

- if the character typed in is a `y` or a `Y` then increment `yesCount` and print out `"YES WAS RECORDED"`
- if the character typed in is an `n` or an `N` then increment `noCount` and print out `"NO WAS RECORDED"`
- if the input is invalid just print the message `"INVALID"` and do nothing else.

Hello, I am having trouble with my C code for this problem. I'm getting incorrect outputs. Any assistance is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
if (response == 'y' || response == 'Y') {
    scanf("%d", &yesCount);
    yesCount++;
    printf("YES WAS RECORDED");
}

if (response == 'n' || response == 'N') {
    scanf("%d", &noCount);
    noCount++;
    printf("NO WAS RECORDED");
} else {
    printf("INVALID");
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the value for `response`?

Comment: The use of a switch would be really efficient for your code

Comment: Why are you calling `scanf` for `yesCount` and `noCount`?  How are you reading `response`?

Answer (score 1):

There might be some typo here because I'm writing from my smartphone. Be aware of that. By the way here as how I would do that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int yescount = 0, nocount = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
          case 'y':
          case 'Y':
            puts("Yes registered");
            yescount++;
            break;

          case 'n':
          case 'N':
            puts("No registered");
            nocount++;
            break;

          default:
            puts("Invalid selection.");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to present your code correctly: it helps a lot with readability and makes many bugs more visible.

There are problems with your code:

- You call `scanf` for no purpose, but you do not read the response as requested.
- You forgot an `else` at the end of the body of the first `if`.  The consequence is that the last `else` branch is taken if the response is `y` or `Y`.
- You should probably print a `\n` after each message so it appears separate from the subsequent output.

Here is a corrected version:

```
scanf("%c", &response);
if (response == 'y' || response == 'Y') {
    yesCount++;
    printf("YES WAS RECORDED\n");
} else
if (response == 'n' || response == 'N') {
    noCount++;
    printf("NO WAS RECORDED\n");
} else {
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

From your comment, they expect you to use `scanf("%c", &response);` to read the `char` into `response`, not the simplest way to read a byte from `stdin`.

Comment: CODELAB ANALYSIS: LOGICAL ERROR(S)


More Hints:
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: &
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: , (comma)
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: scanf

Problems Detected:
     ⇒     The contents of your standard output is incorrect.
     ⇒     The value of noCount is incorrect.
     ⇒     The value of response is incorrect.
     ⇒     The value of yesCount is incorrect.
     ⇒     For More Information: VIEW TEST CASE TABLE
This is what I am getting when i submit the problem

Comment: I updated the answer.  It is unclear whether you are supposed to write a piece of code or a compilable function.  If yesCount and noCount are *given*, you should only change them as instructed, but try `yesCount = noCount = 0;` to check if they expect you to initialize them to `0`.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: @user44775: Can you please click on the grey check mark below the answer score to mark it as accepted?